# how to call 'onbeforeprint' function in Firefox

Tags: printing, firefox-addon

I'm developing one `firefox extension`. In that I need to inject some `html` elements, when `print` function is called, into the web page that has been loaded in the current browser tab. And then the page should be taken to the printer along with the injected `html` elements

I searched for and find `onbeforeprint` function in mdc

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/HTMLBodyElement

I'm unaware of using function. I tried using it as an event.

`window.addEventListener("onbeforeprint",`
`function(){alert("Print called");},` 
`false);`

But it fails. Please, kindly help me in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, this feature was added just recently, and will only be available in Firefox 5 or 6.